# specific homotopy groups of $\textrm{Gr}(n,m)$ --- $\pi_0$, $\pi_n$, $\pi_m$, $\pi_{n+m}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces, grassmannian, homogeneous-spaces

Given a real Grassmanians
$$\textrm{Gr}(n,m)=O(n+m)/O(n)\times O(m)$$
could we determine the following specific homotopy groups:
$$\pi_0\textrm{Gr}(n,m)=?$$
$$\pi_n\textrm{Gr}(n,m)=?$$
$$\pi_m\textrm{Gr}(n,m)=?$$
$$\pi_{n+m}\textrm{Gr}(n,m)=?$$

You can provide partial answers. No need to be complete if some of the answers are too harsh. We can boil down the answer by writing in terms of homotopy groups of $O(n+m)$, $O(n)$, $ O(m)$.

We take $n,m \geq 1$.

Comment: For example is $\pi_0\textrm{Gr}(n,m)=0?$

Comment: $O(n+m)$ has two path components and $O(n) \times O(m)$ intersects both of them meaning that $Gr(n,m)$ has one path component. I.e $\pi_0(Gr(n,m)) = 0$.

Comment: I am also tempted to say that $\pi_n(Gr(n,m)) = \pi_{n+1}(O(\infty))$ for big enough $m$ but am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks Noel for comment +1